# Any current replacement for ASIHTTPRequest for HTTPS request and REST-based services

Tags: ios, rest, https, asihttprequest

I'm updating development for an application in iOS

this app currently uses a framework called ASIHTTPRequest for performing basic HTTP requests and interacting with REST-based services.

I wanted an upgrade but it says framework was no longer supported since 2011!!!!

is there any update, fork or alternative for performing such operations? I'm thinking performing **HTTPS** request and interacting with REST-based services.

Comment: Generally speaking `ASIHTTPRequest` still works. Otherwise, you should take a look at `AFNetworking` or `Alamofire` or simply just making your own `NSURLSession`, it's much simpler now than it was at the time libraries like `ASIHTTPRequest` created.

Comment: If developing for Swift, consider [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). If developing for Objective-C, consider [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: I'll try AFNetworking then, it's for objective-c, thanks!!!